# Laravel's AuthController doesn't validate my fields properly

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am writing an application in Laravel 5.1. According to the documentation I can authenticate and validate my login forms using their AuthController.

**The only field I want to validate is a `code-input` field.**

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="code-input">Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="code-input" class="form-control" id="code-input" placeholder="Type your code here">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, **whenever I set my validation method in the AuthController to check only that field and submit an empty form I get an error** that the email field is required and the password field is required. I mean, what?

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'code-input' => 'required|max:255'
    ]);
}
```

[image: Error message]

My routes are also working correctly:

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('/', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

**Does anybody know what is going on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validator` method is just for creating users (registration). Login is all handled by the [AuthenticatesUsers](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) trait `postLogin` method, which requires email and password.

There are ways to change the "email" requirement easily, but to get rid of both fields and replace with a code, you'll have to write yourself a new `postLogin` method.

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave me the most insight into the problem and now I know what to do!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the `postLogin` function at **AuthenticatesUsers.php**? It could have a line of codes something like this which results the validation errors:

```
$this->validate($request, [
   $this->loginUsername() => 'required', 'password' => 'required',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, but andrewtweber had the most insightful answer from those two.